Why am I getting number instead of Date in Excel VBA?
Here is the code:
Function CurrentDate() As Date
CurrentDate = Date
End Function

But in excel sheet I'm getting 45418.


Format cells as Date in Excel dates are stored as number so you get the output as number.

Why do you need vba for this? use today() or now() directly in the sheet with the cell formatted correctly for the date format you want.

I'm learning vba actually.

Format your cell as date and it'll work.
Excel stores any date later than 31.12.1899 as number of days starting from 01.01.1900. It's made this way so that you can do calculations with dates. Basically, dates are numbers as far as Excel is concerned.
Any date earlier than 01.01.1900 is stored as plain text (a string), not as a number. Thus, calculations with them are impossible.

"Any date earlier than that is stored as plain text": It's important to note that this is a text string for Excel, not a date. You can't calculate with it, you can't use it for sorting and the like. And having a negative number in a cell that is formatted as date will lead to "#####"

Thank you, I updated my answer to clarify things. Original was a bit misleading.
